# Unexpected request: GET No more request expected at $httpBackend

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, httpbackend

I have a function in my scope to retrieve the status of my service when the user clicks a button, or
  when some event are triggered and this function is automatically called.

This is my function, defined in the controller I am using:

```
$scope.getStatus = function() {
  $http({method: 'GET', url: config.entrypoint + config.api + '/outbound/service/' + $scope.serviceId})
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.errorMessage = '';
      $scope.serviceAllGood = data;
    })
    .error(function() {
      $scope.serviceAllGood = '';
      $scope.errorMessage = 'We are experiencing problems retrieving your service status.';
    });
  }
```

The unit test is made like:

```
describe('SendServiceCtrl', function(){
    var scope, ctrl, $httpBackend, configuration;

    beforeEach(function () {
      module('papi', 'ngUpload');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller, config) {
      configuration = config;
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
      $httpBackend.expectGET(configuration.entrypoint + configuration.api + "/user/outboundstatus/").respond(200, {"meta":{"apiVersion":"0.1","code":200,"errors":null},"response":{"allowed":false}});
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      ctrl = $controller('SendServiceCtrl', {$scope: scope});
  }));

  it('Should get the status', function() {

    scope.serviceId = '09bb5943fa2881e1';
    scope.getStatus();
    $httpBackend.whenGET(configuration.entrypoint + configuration.api + '/outbound/service/' + scope.serviceId).respond(200, {"meta":{"apiVersion":"0.1","code":200,"errors":null}});

  });

});
```

In the unit test I have also other $httpBackend tests on the same controller, but all of them works just somoothely. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to supply the `whenGET` *before* you call the method.

```
it('Should get the status', function() {
    scope.serviceId = '09bb5943fa2881e1';
    $httpBackend.whenGET(configuration.entrypoint + configuration.api + '/outbound/service/' + scope.serviceId).respond(200, {"meta":{"apiVersion":"0.1","code":200,"errors":null}});
    scope.getStatus();
});
```

Set up the expectation of the request then trigger the request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: templates then cause this failure as well.

Comment: Do you think that using `$templateCache` like `ui.bootstrap` does would nullify the need of mocking the GET?

Comment: @domokun Can you post a link to where that is used?

Comment: @domokun if you look closer, they used inline HTML elements as opposed to load templates from a real file.

Comment: @P.M "jsified" templates to be precise, with `grunt-html2js` plugin