# HTTP request to external JSON causes "Error: Unexpected request: GET https://...json"

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http

Hi I am requesting a JSON file from an external URL https://...json.

When running my tests it causes an unexpected error even though I did not write any tests on my functions yet. Only the tests for my controller fail (at the $scope.$digest()).

My code looks as follows

Service:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('dealService',['$http','$location',function($http,$location){
  this.deals = function () {
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://myurl.com/deals.json'
    }).then(function (response) {
      return response.data;
    });
  };
}]);
```

This returns an array which I then take as promise such as
Controller:

```
$scope.dealsLanding = [];
        dealService.deals().then(function (deals) {
          $scope.dealsLanding = deals;
        });
```

This however seems to cause my tests to fail. Error: Unexpected request: GET https://myurl.com/deals.json No more request expected.

What can I do about it?

Comment: This looks like this angular error: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18148691/16959

Comment: This may help you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779528/unexpected-request-get-no-more-request-expected-at-httpbackend

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I read those articles, but why do these functions mess with my tests even though I do not even touch them?